# Getting Crash with AWSS3PutObjectRequest

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am using the AWS SDK like this way

Properties declaration :

```
@property (nonatomic, strong)AWSStaticCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider;
@property (nonatomic, strong)AWSServiceConfiguration * configuration;
@property (nonatomic, strong)AWSS3 *s3;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AWSS3PutObjectRequest *putrequest;
```

And Implementation like this way

```
  AccessKeys * accessKeys = [ECSGlobals sharedInstance].accessKeys;
    self.credentialsProvider = [AWSStaticCredentialsProvider    credentialsWithAccessKey:accessKeys.accessKeyId secretKey:accessKeys.secretAccessKey];
    self.configuration = [AWSServiceConfiguration configurationWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1    credentialsProvider:self.credentialsProvider];
    self.s3 = [[AWSS3 alloc] initWithConfiguration:self.configuration];
    self.putrequest = [AWSS3PutObjectRequest new];


NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.2);
[imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];


long long fileSize = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:savedImagePath error:nil][NSFileSize] longLongValue];


self.putrequest.bucket = bucketName;
self.putrequest.key = imageName;
self.putrequest.contentType = @"image/jpeg";
self.putrequest.body = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:savedImagePath];
self.putrequest.contentLength =  [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:fileSize];
[[self.s3 putObject:self.putrequest] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
    NSLog(@"Amazon error : %@", [task error]);
    return nil;
}];
```

But I am getting crash

[CFError retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7f2daff0

I have checked all properties are strong. Not sure why I am getting this crash.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. We are getting this issue as some how saved image path become nil before coming in use. So there is no image data sending to AWS.

After fixing this, images are uploading successfully.